# Check for bad practices/improvements

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to coding yet not completely inexperienced. Working on a school assignment regarding financial calculators. Would be great if any of you could take a look at my code for bad practices/possible improvements etc.

I did add a 'animated' startup (with a lot of printf to show "financial calculator" but couldn't fit it in, is it a good idea to do something like that?)

option_2 and option_4 are left as placeholders for the time being while my group works on other 2 calculators.

```
//ASSIGNMENT_041118
//libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>

//files

//colours
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLACK    "\x1b[30m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED      "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN    "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW   "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE     "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA  "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN     "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_WHITE    "\x1b[37m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BBLACK   "\x1b[90m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BRED     "\x1b[91m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BGREEN   "\x1b[92m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BYELLOW  "\x1b[93m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BBLUE    "\x1b[94m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BMAGENTA "\x1b[95m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BCYAN    "\x1b[96m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BWHITE   "\x1b[97m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET    "\x1b[0m"


//function prototype declaration
int main_menu();
int login();
float compound();
float compound_calc(float n, float initial_savings, float rate, float time);
float option_2();
float mortgage();
float option_4();

int main()
{
    system("color 0F");
    login();
    return (0);
}



int login()
{
    char username[20];
    char password[20];
    int l_option;

    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    printf("Enter your username (case sensitive): ");
    scanf("%s", &username);

    printf("\nEnter your password (case sensitive): ");
    scanf("%s", &password);

    if (strcmp(username, "user") == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(password, "0000") == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
            return main_menu();
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"ERROR - WRONG PASSWORD\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            do {
                printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("[1]Retry\n[0]Exit\n");
                printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                scanf("%d", &l_option);
                switch (l_option)
                {
                case 1:
                    system("cls");
                    return login();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    system("cls");
                    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                    printf("EXIT\n");
                    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    system("cls");
                    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                    printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED "INVALID OPTION - CHOOSE AGAIN\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                    break;
                }
            } while (l_option != 1 && l_option != 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"ERROR - USER DOESN'T EXIST\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);

        do {
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("[1]Retry\n[0]Exit\n");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            scanf("%d", &l_option);
            switch (l_option)
            {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                return login();
                break;
            case 0:
                system("cls");
                printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                printf("EXIT\n");
                printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                system("cls");
                printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
                printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED "INVALID OPTION - CHOOSE AGAIN\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                break;
            }
        } while (l_option != 1 && l_option != 0);
    }
}

int main_menu()
{
    int option_main;
    do {
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        printf("Choose an option:\n"); //tells user to select an option
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BGREEN"[1] <Savings Calculator - Compounded Interest> \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET); //displays options
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BMAGENTA"[2] <place_holder_2> \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BYELLOW"[3] <Mortage calculator> \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BCYAN"[4] <place_holder_3> \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
        printf("\n[0] <Exit system>\n");
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        scanf("%d", &option_main); //accepts input for function selection
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        system("cls");

        switch (option_main) //switch case for main option
        {
        case 1:
        {
            compound();
            break;
        }

        case 2:/*option_2*/
        {
            option_2();
            break;
        }

        case 3:/*option_3*/
        {
            mortgage();
            break;
        }

        case 4:/*option_4*/
        {
            option_4();
            break;
        }

        case 0:/*exit*/
        {
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<EXIT>\n");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"INVALID OPTION - CHOOSE AGAIN\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            break;
        }

        }

    } while (option_main != 1 && option_main != 2 && option_main != 3 && option_main != 4 && option_main != 0);

    return (0);
}

float compound() //compound_interest_calculation_self_defined function
{
    int compound_type, ci_option;
    float n, initial_savings, rate, time, final_savings;

    do {
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BGREEN"<Savings Calculator - Compounded Interest>\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET); //displays option selected (Savings Calculator - Compounded Interest)
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Please enter compound type:\n"); //Prompts user to choose 
        printf("[1] Monthly\n[2] Quarterly\n[3] Semiannually\n[4] Annually\n\n[9]Return to menu\n[0] Exit\n");//displays options
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        scanf("%d", &compound_type); //accepts input for option selection
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        system("cls");

    switch (compound_type) //internal switch case for compounded interest calculator
        {
        case 1: /*monthly*/
            n = 12;
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<Monthly compound>\n");
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Please enter initial amount of savings: RM "); //prompts user for initial saving amount (principle)
            scanf("%f", &initial_savings); //accepts input for initial savings
                                           /*printf("Please enter monthly deposit: RM "); //prompts user input for monthly deposit
                                           scanf("%f", &monthly_deposit); */ //accepts input for monthly deposit
            printf("Please enter interest rate (decimal): "); //prompts user input for interest rate
            scanf("%f", &rate); //accepts input for interest rate
            printf("Please enter time (year): "); //prompts input for saving duration
            scanf("%f", &time); //accepts input for saving duration
            final_savings = compound_calc(n, initial_savings, rate, time);
            printf("\nThe final savings is: RM %.2f \n", final_savings); //dispays final savings amount
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            break;

        case 2: /*quarterly*/
            n = 4;
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<Quarterly compound>\n");
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Please enter initial amount of savings: RM ");
            scanf("%f", &initial_savings);
            /*printf("Please enter monthly deposit: RM "); //temporarily removed from calculation
            scanf("%f", &monthly_deposit);*/
            printf("Please enter interest rate (decimal): ");
            scanf("%f", &rate);
            printf("Please enter time (year): ");
            scanf("%f", &time);
            final_savings = compound_calc(n, initial_savings, rate, time);
            printf("\nThe final savings is: RM %.2f \n", final_savings);
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            break;

        case 3: /*semiannually*/
            n = 2;
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<Semiannual compound>\n");
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Please enter initial amount of savings: RM ");
            scanf("%f", &initial_savings);
            /*printf("Please enter monthly deposit: RM "); //temporarily removed from calculation
            scanf("%f", &monthly_deposit);*/
            printf("Please enter interest rate (decimal): ");
            scanf("%f", &rate);
            printf("Please enter time (year): ");
            scanf("%f", &time);
            final_savings = compound_calc(n, initial_savings, rate, time);
            printf("\nThe final savings is: RM %.2f \n", final_savings);
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            break;

        case 4: /*annually*/
            n = 1;
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<Annual compound>\n");
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Please enter initial amount of savings: RM ");
            scanf("%f", &initial_savings);
            /*printf("Please enter monthly deposit: RM "); //temporarily removed from calculation
            scanf("%f", &monthly_deposit);*/
            printf("Please enter interest rate (decimal): ");
            scanf("%f", &rate);
            printf("Please enter time (year): ");
            scanf("%f", &time);
            final_savings = compound_calc(n, initial_savings, rate, time);
            printf("\nThe final savings is: RM %.2f\n", final_savings);
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            break;

        case 9: /*return to menu*/
            return main_menu();
            break;

        case 0: /*exit*/
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<EXIT> \n");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            exit(0);

        default:/*any other input*/
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"INVALID OPTION - CHOOSE AGAIN\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);//When user inputs invalid option for compound type
        }

    } while (compound_type != 0 && compound_type != 1 && compound_type != 2 && compound_type != 3 && compound_type != 4 && compound_type != 9);

    do
    {
        printf("[1]Back to compound interest calculator\n[9]Return to menu\n[0] Exit\n");
        printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
        scanf("%d", &ci_option);

        switch (ci_option)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            return compound();
            break;

        case 9:
            system("cls");
            return main_menu();
            break;

        case 0:
            system("cls");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<EXIT>\n");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:/*any other input*/
            system("cls");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"INVALID OPTION - CHOOSE AGAIN\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");


        }

    } while (ci_option != 1 && ci_option != 9 && ci_option != 0);

    return(0);
}

float compound_calc(float n, float initial_savings, float rate, float time)
{
    float CI;
    CI = (initial_savings*(pow((1 + rate / n), (n * time))));
    return (CI);
}

float option_2()
{
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_BMAGENTA"<place_holder_2> selected \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    return(0);
}

float mortgage()
{
    float house_price, down_percentage, interest_rate, monthly_payment, r, p;//variables declaration
    int loan_period, n,m_option;

    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_BYELLOW"<Home mortgage calculator>\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET); //displays option selected (Savings Calculator - Compounded Interest)
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Insert property price: RM ");//prompt input
    scanf("%f", &house_price);//get input
    printf("Insert down percentage (decimal): ");
    scanf("%f", &down_percentage);
    printf("Insert loan period (Years): ");
    scanf("%d", &loan_period);
    printf("Insert interest rate (decimal):");
    scanf("%f", &interest_rate);

    r = interest_rate / 12;
    n = loan_period * 12;
    p = house_price - house_price *down_percentage;

    monthly_payment = p *(r*pow((1 + r), n)) / (pow((1 + r), n) - 1);//calculate monthly payment //NOTE:MOVE TO SELF DEFINED FUNCTION
    printf("\nYour monthly payment is %.2f \n", monthly_payment);//display output

    do
    {
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    printf("[3]Recalculate\n[9]Return to menu\n[0] Exit\n");
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    scanf("%d", &m_option);

        switch (m_option)
        {
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            return mortgage();
            break;

        case 9:
            system("cls");
            return main_menu();
            break;

        case 0:
            system("cls");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf("<EXIT>\n");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:/*any other input*/
            system("cls");
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
            printf(ANSI_COLOR_BRED"ERROR: INVALID OPTION \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            printf("=========================================================================================================\n");

        }

    } while (m_option != 3 && m_option != 9 && m_option != 0);

    return (0);
}

float option_4()
{
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_BCYAN"<place_holder_4> selected \n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
    printf("=========================================================================================================\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Tip: next time, post a [mcve] with a move toward _minimal_ on your part.

Comment: If the code is working you should present it at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and not here.

Comment: alk, oh ok sorry, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your "scanf();" to "fgets();"

> char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char Name[50];
int main(){
    printf("What is your name?\n> ");
    fgets(Name,50,stdin); //Gets user input from stdin (not from file)
    /* But the problem is that fgets also includes '\n' so we put: */
    Name[strcspn(Name,"\r\n")]=0; //Removes '\n'
    printf("Your name is: <%s>\n",Name);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A concern with using `fgets()` is mixing with the other `scanf("%d", &l_option);` like code to scan numbers.  Those tend to leave a `'\n'` in `stdin` and fool  following `fgets()`. Best for learners never to use `scanf()` at all until they know why.